# On form submit link to a url including the input value

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to link directly to a url such as index/link/product-name, where value was the inputted value on the form. I don't want it to go to index/link.php?product-name=value. Is there a way to do that?

```
    <form id="search" class="header_form" action="">
        <input id="product-name" class="header_search" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" required>
        <span>
        <input type="button" value="Search">
        </span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Its not related to jquery , html :) u need php , htaccess configuration. jQuery has some limitations too,else we never needed php.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you type is goin t something in the textfield is going to  update the action of your form:

```
$("#product-name").keyup(function(){
$("#search").attr('action',"index/link/"+$(this).val());
```

});